# Index on UTC Date Time Column and TO_CHAR

Tags: database, oracle, datetime, indexing, to-char

We have index on a **column** which is of Physical Type **UTC Date Time** and in one of the code we have used this column under where clause as below:

```
where
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(**<column>**,'MM-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS') >  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(RUN_DATE,'MM-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM-DD-YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Our DBA marked out this usage of **TO_CHAR** will ensure that index will never be used.

Can you please help me understand if this stands true/false and reasoning behind this. Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you performing a date-to-string-back-to-date conversion in the first place? `to_date(to_char(x))`. Doesn't that seem redundant?  And I see 2 columns being referenced in your `where` clause. Are they both of the same type? are they both indexed? Which index would you expect the optimizer to use (unclear without a full query). And finally, what is the actual Oracle data type of your 2 columns? I don't know what you mean by `UTC Date Time`.

Comment: Thats what i have figured out as well. Both are of same data type, so no reason to do TO_DATE(TO_CHAR), But i have seen this in many places. Is there possible reason for this i wonder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions almost always prevent an index from being used.  In this case, though, you appear to be comparing the value of two columns, so indexes are rarely used in that case either.

If you do really want an index for this purpose, you could consider a couple things.  First, you might store one of the columns as a difference one other . . .  For instance, if the first column is a creation date and the second a run date, then you could store days-to-run date instead of the date itself.

Another possibility is to index the difference:

```
create index idx_t_col1_col2
    on t(col1 - col2)
```

Then in the code you can write:

```
where (col1 - col2) = 0
```

or:

```
where (col1 - col2) >= 0 and (col1 - col2) < 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding color to Gordon's answer (which is the correct answer and should be marked so).

First, it may help you to learn how to use EXPLAIN PLAN. In Toad or SQL Developer (if you use one of these front-ends to interact with your database) it's as easy as running a query - you just click a different button and you get the EXPLAIN PLAN.

First question: If you wrap a date within to_date(to_char(...), ...) with an identical and full mask for both functions, is the optimizer smart enough to sense that and to remove both functions and just use that date? Answer: NO; EXPLAIN PLAN shows that the predicate is NOT simplified as suggested here. It also shows that `date_column > SYSDATE` will use an index, but if you wrap the date column within to_date(to_char(.....)) then the engine will perform a full table scan (it will NOT use the index).

Second question: Might the inequality cause this problem even without the function calls? Comparing the date column (indexed, not wrapped within functions) to SYSDATE uses the index.

Comparing two columns, the first one is Primary Key and the second is NOT INDEXED, results in a full scan (caused by the comparison, with no functions wrapped around either column).

Does an index on the other column (in addition to the Primary Key on the first column) help with an inequality filter? Answer: no. Again, after creating an index on the second column and running EXPLAIN PLAN again, the table is still full-scanned. Exactly as Gordon explained.